# Image Insert error with Twitter Bootstrap 3 Modal and Tinymce Editor

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, tinymce-4

When I am loading tinymce in Bootstrap Modal.

All the popup image insert, URL insert, Source code opions doesnot work.

**Here is JsFiddle :- http://jsfiddle.net/n9e63/**

HTML Code :-

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
          <textarea class="form-control" id="message"></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Here is Javascript Code :-

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea#message",
    theme: "modern",
    plugins: [
        "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
        "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen",
        "insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality",
        "emoticons template paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern"
    ],
    toolbar1: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image",
    toolbar2: "print preview media | forecolor backcolor emoticons",
    image_advtab: true,
    templates: [
        {title: 'Test template 1', content: 'Test 1'},
        {title: 'Test template 2', content: 'Test 2'}
    ]
});
```

**JsFIDDLE URL :- http://jsfiddle.net/n9e63/**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your code:

```
$(document).on('focusin', function(event) {
    if ($(event.target).closest(".mce-window").length) {
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    }
});
```

fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/n9e63/6/